# Rapidly fragmenting index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which currently runs on two physical servers just fine in around 7 seconds. The query is relatively complex as it joins several tables and is formed by Entity Framework. I'm currently migrating the database to a virtually hosted environment and everything seems to be ok with the exception of this one query. When querying against the virtually hosted SQL Server instance the query initially runs in 7 seconds but after an hour or two will suddenly take around 8 minutes.

Looking at the execution plan whilst in the slow state I identified an unexpected full table scan. If I rebuild the index on that table it instantly reverts to taking 7 seconds. However, within an hour or so it will switch to taking 8 minutes.

The table in question has very little change and often I have been able to determine zero change between it running well and running slowly. After rebuilding the index, fragmentation drops to around 0.02% but within an hour or two it jumps to between 50%-60%.

- Page fullness – 52.95%
- Total fragmentation – 54.19%
- Average row size – 338
- Depth – 3
- Forwarded records – 0
- Ghost records – 0
- Index type – CLUSTERED INDEX
- Leaf-level rows – 134900
- Maximum row size – 604
- Minimum row size – 239
- Pages – 10736
- Partition ID – 1
- Version ghost rows – 0

I don’t know for certain whether the fragmentation is causing the issue but I am at a complete loss as to why it may be fragmenting so quickly. Can anyone explain?

Comment: +1 for an interesting problem

Comment: Do you have shrink database scheduled? This could fragment indexes. Also, what's the table clustered on?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. No shrink database scheduled. The table is clustered on its [int] primary key.

Comment: What is interesting here is 52% full page. This could be an indication of large number of page splits. But then again, you say there's not many updates on the table. Pls check the page splits counter for a time period.

Comment: I may have this wrong but I've checked for page splits in the transaction log `SELECT count(*) FROM fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) WHERE operation = 'LOP_DELETE_SPLIT'` and it returns zero records. Please excuse me if I have misunderstood this though. It isn't an area I'm entirely familiar with.

Comment: Tha database is in simple recovery model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can see the differences of [many fragmentation techniques](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/indexes/fragmentation-resolutions) and see what is the most appropriate for your case.
- FILL FACTOR could also impact the fragmentation.
- STATISTICS on that table might not be updated
- You might be a victim by parameter sniffing problem ( a query plan is cached but not the most optimal). Can you check if the [same query plan](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/sqlserver/how-to/list-cached-query-plans) is used for both cases?
- Are you sure the both queries are identical? If not, what is the difference?

We might help you more if you put the a print-screen with fragmentation info from [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/detecting-fragmentation-all-indexes-tsql-script) when the query works well, respectively bad.

**Later edit:**
With the default fill factor, when a page split occurs half of the rows are kept in the initial page and the other half will be moved to a new page.

You have very little change but for sure the number of pages doubles, so I suspect a "little update" that is made on all (or almost all) rows in the table due to that 53% internal fragmentation.

Other actions to be performed:

- 1/ It will be useful to post your table structure, to have a look at.
- 2/ Do you have any column with CHAR data type?
- 3/ List average number of rows in the page (fast vs slow)
- 4/ Check all stored procedures/queries that touch that table
- 5/ Add a trigger and log (in another table?) the actions performed on your table (you might have `UPDATE TableX SET colA = colA WHERE 1=1`)

Keeps us posted.

Comment: I've managed to capture the differences from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats between fast and slow states. (Fast -> Slow respectively)
avg_fragmentation_in_percent: 0.245916037% -> 55.98215116%
fragment_count: 433 -> 10179
avg_fragment_size_in_pages: 13.147806 -> 1.056783574
page_count: 5693 -> 10757

Comment: I set a scheduled task to capture the index stats every minute. It shows there's not ramp up, it just jumps to 53% fragmentation and instantly the query is slow. As expected when it becomes slow the execution plan changes.

[Image](http://www.andyreedphotography.co.uk/Temp/Dev/image001.png)

Comment: @AndyReed: any news about?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I have been diverted. As you advised I added a trigger to capture change on the table. It turns out there is change. I haven't yet managed to track down the process but it seems as though rows are being updated and then just a few minutes later being changed back to their original state. This churn involves a datetime fields which I'm assuming must be causing the page splits.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, index fragmentation could cause the performance degradation as well. It could happen because of DML to that table.

You see the page fullness is about 52%. you have 10736 number of pages with clustered index, imagine when performed select query with full index scan, it will travel through the pages until it get the match record. It will cost you the performance.

Fragmentation could happen, and it is normal to have table maintenance to rebuild the index. But I think fragmentation reach above 30% within one hour is good. I am not sure how it happen since you did not provide detail information.

Maybe what you can do is:

1. Check back what indexes do you have in this table.
2. What Query touch the table

Waiting feedback from you..